# How to create a custom Perl distribution

Tags: perl, cpan

I would create a custom Perl distribution for perl-5.30.0.tar.gz.
I would include in the perl-5.30.0.tar.gz following Perl modules

```
HTML::Entities
HTML::Strip
Devel::CheckLib
Net::DNS
Mail::DKIM::Verifier 
LWP::Simple
Net::LDAP
IO::Socket
IO::Socket::SSL
IO::Socket::INET6
Net::SSLeay
Digest::MD5
DB_File
DBI::DBD
DBIx::Mysql::InformationSchema
DBD::mysqlPP
DBD::mysql
DBD::MariaDB
Email::MIME
Email::Send
Net::SMTP::SSL
Number::Compare
MIME::Body
MIME::Types
Regexp::Optimizer 
Sys::Syslog
Sys::MemInfo
Text::Iconv
Text::Glob
Tie::DBI
Time::Local
Time::ParseDate
```

so that at the end of the Perl installation the Perl modules will be already installed and ready to use.

Is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: [Carton](http://p3rl.org/Carton)?

Comment: I will check thanks